# Is there an explicit formula for the expression $(a\mathbb{Z}+b) \cap (a'\mathbb{Z}+b'),$ not involving $\cap$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Thinking of $\mathbb{Z}$ as a ring, the *ideals* of $\mathbb{Z}$ are precisely those subsets of the form $a\mathbb{Z}.$ Hence intersections of ideals can be computed by taking lowest common multiples. In particular: $$a\mathbb{Z} \cap b \mathbb{Z} = \mathrm{lcm}(a,b)\mathbb{Z}$$

Now the *cosets* of $\mathbb{Z}$ are more general; these are precisely those subsets of the form $a\mathbb{Z}+b$. Suppose we wish to compute the intersection of two cosets, i.e. we're interested in the expression: $$(a\mathbb{Z}+b) \cap (a'\mathbb{Z}+b')$$

> **Question.** Is there an explicit formula for this expression, not involving $\cap$?
>
> If not, does assuming $a$ and $a'$ are coprime help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no explicit formula per se. The problem is exactly equivalent to solving the congruences
$$x\equiv b\pmod a\\x\equiv b'\pmod {a'}$$
modulo $\mathrm{lcm}(a,a')$.

If $a,a'$ are coprime, then we can apply the Chinese remainder theorem and Euclid's algorithm. The intersection will then be $$aa'\mathbb Z+x.$$

If $a,a'$ are not coprime, then the intersection could be empty. If it is not empty, we will be able to simplify the congruences to the first case in order to be able to use the Chinese remainder theorem.

Comment: Is there an explicit formula for $x$?

Comment: There's no explicit formula, although there are efficient algorithms  (Euclid's algorithm) to calculate it. But then lcm isn't exactly a formula either - and it is calculated using Euclid's algorithm.

Comment: In the coprime case, you could say that $x = (a'b+ab')(a+a')^{-1}\pmod {aa'}$ where the inverse is taken modulo $aa'$, but that relies on finding the inverse to $a+a'$ which would require something akin to Euclid's algorithm anyway.

Comment: Hmm okay. So is it theorem that $a+a'$ is always a unit in $\mathbb{Z}/aa'\mathbb{Z}$ if $a$ and $a'$ are coprime?

Comment: Yes. If a prime $p\mid aa'$ then $p\mid a$ or $p\mid a'$. So if in addition $p\mid a+a'$, then $p\mid a$ and $p\mid a'$. Hence $a+a'$ and $aa'$ are coprime.